# need to shift bits in number using bitwise operators?

Tags: bit-manipulation

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,m,n,t,res,i;
    printf("Enter number\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for(i=31;i>=0;i--)
    {
        printf("%d",((num>>i)&1));
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter position 1 and position 2\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    printf("enter number\n");
    scanf("%d",&t);

    res=((num&(~(((~(unsigned)0)>>(32-((m-t)+1)))<<t)))&(num&(~(((~(unsigned)0)>>(32-((n-t)+1)))<<t))))|(((((num&((((~(unsigned)0)>>(((m-t))))<<(n))))>>(m-t))))|(((num&((((~(unsigned)0)>>(((32-n))))<<(32-t))))<<(m-t))));

    for(i=31;i>=0;i--)
    {
         printf("%d",(res>>i)&1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I need to swap bits from (m to m-t) and (n to n-t) in number num.I tried the above code but it doesn't work..can someone please help.

Comment: Um, can you describe how it is not working?  For example, can you add an input, the expected output, and the actual output?

Comment: Enter number..                                                                            
127                                                                                                            
00000000000000000000000001111111                              
Enter position 1 and position 2..                                          
22 5
enter number..
3..
0000000000000000000000000000111                                                   But the actual output should be as      0000001110000000000000000100011

Comment: @yedukondalu are you sure the output shouldn't be 00000000001110000000000001100011? Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual with bit swapping problems, you can save a few instructions by using xor.

```
unsigned f(unsigned num, unsigned n, unsigned m, unsigned t) {
    n -= t; m -= t;
    unsigned mask = ((unsigned) 1 << t) - 1;
    unsigned nm = ((num >> n) ^ (num >> m)) & mask;
    return num ^ (nm << n) ^ (nm << m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you break it down into smaller steps.

First, make a bit mask t bits wide. You can do this by subtracting 1 from a power of 2, like this:

```
int mask = (1 << t) - 1;
```

For example if t is 3 then mask will be 7 (111 in binary).

Then you can make a copy of num and clear the bits in the range of m to m-t and n to n-t by shifting up the mask, NOTing it and ANDing, so that only bits not covered by the mask remain set:

```
res = num & ~(mask<<(m-t)) & ~(mask<<(n-t));
```

Then you can shift the bits in the two ranges into their proper locations and OR with the result. You can do this by shifting down by (n-t), masking, and then shifting up by (m-t), then vice versa:

```
res |= ((num >> (n-t)) & mask) << (m-t);
res |= ((num >> (m-t)) & mask) << (n-t);
```

The bits are now in the correct place.

You could do this in one line like this:

```
res = (num & ~(mask<<(m-t)) & ~(mask<<(n-t))) | (((num >> (n-t)) & mask) << (m-t)) | (((num >> (m-t)) & mask) << (n-t));
```

And it can be simplified by doing the m-t and n-t subtractions beforehand, assuming you don't want to use the values afterwards:

```
m -= t; n -= t;
res = (num & ~(mask<<m) & ~(mask<<n)) | (((num >> n)) & mask) << m) | (((num >> m) & mask) << n);
```

This doesn't work if the two ranges overlap. It's not clear what the correct behaviour would be in that case.